# Is there a JS function for generating a dataset based on combinations of multiple sets

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a unit test for my function below

```
const f1 = (a:boolean, b:1|2|3, c:'apple'|'banana') => {...}
```

Is there a function that, given the possible values for each arguments of function f1(), returns an array of all combinations:

```
[
  [true, 1, 'apple'],
  [true, 1, 'banana'],
  [true, 2, 'apple'],
  ...,
  [false, 3, 'banana']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together the following grid search function for that very purpose. There is an example usage at the end.

```js
function gridSearch(vars) {
  let all = [];
  for (let prop in vars) {
    if (!vars.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
    if (!Array.isArray(vars[prop])) vars[prop] = [vars[prop]];
    all.push(vars[prop].map(val => ({ [prop]: val })));
  }

  function cartesian() {
    var r = [],
      arg = arguments,
      max = arg.length - 1;
    function helper(arr, i) {
      for (var j = 0, l = arg[i].length; j < l; j++) {
        var a = arr.slice(0);
        a.push(arg[i][j]);
        if (i == max) r.push(a);
        else helper(a, i + 1);
      }
    }
    helper([], 0);
    return r;
  }

  let permutations = cartesian(...all);
  let final = [];
  permutations.forEach(permutation => {
    final.push(permutation.reduce((r, c) => ({ ...r, ...c }), {}));
  });

  return final;
}

const obj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [true, false],
  c: "foo"
}

const permutations = gridSearch(obj);

console.log(permutations);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function to do this.  This type of activity generally falls in the category of "combinatorics".  Checkout [js-combinatorics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics) if you are interested in using an NPM pacakge.